# Update array several times in less time

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to do several updates to my array based on commands provided. I want to reduce time complexity for it.

I have an array of integers A and another 2 dimensional list that represents commands

The command format is like this:

1. `[1, p, q]`, if it is type 1, then pick item at index p in array A and set its value to q
2. `[2, -1, r]`, if it is type 2, then find all items in array A which are less than r and update them to r, the value -1 has no significance , we can ignore that.

**Example:**

```
A = [2,4,1,4]

commands = {[1,1,30], [1,2,4], [2,-1,10]};

Result = [10,30,10,10]

Explanation:

command1 = [1,1,30] , A = [2,4,1,4] changes to [2,30,1,4]
command2 = [1,2,4] , A = [2,30,1,4] changes to [2,30,4,4]
command3 = [2,-1,10], A = [2,30,4,4] changes to [10,30,10,10]

so result is [10,30,10,10]
```

Here is my code:

```
public static int[] solve(int n, int[] A, int[][] commands) {
    for (int[] command : commands) {
        if (command[0] == 1) {
            int p = command[1];
            int q = command[2];
            A[p] = q;
        } else if (command[0] == 2) {
            int r = command[2];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (A[i] < r) {
                    A[i] = r;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

Size of my array is up to 10^5 and commands is up to 10^9.

How to reduce time complexity for this. Using `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` inside else if condition is taking lot of time, I want to reduce that.

Comment: You shouldn't subtract 1 to adjust for 0-based indexing. From your example, it looks like the input commands already use 0-based indexing.

Comment: To reduce time complexity, think about the _algorithm_, not just the code. Can you possibly omit some commands if later commands will negate the effect of the present command?

Comment: Magic numbers are confusing; maybe basing your class on an `enum` would help?

Comment: @k314159, I updated code, by removing 1, it was type error

Comment: *"b) [2, -1, r]"* can i know what is the use of -1 here?

Comment: @GrindingForReputation, the -1 has no significance , we can ignore that

Comment: I can see ways to reduce the size of n by eliminating commands whose effects will be overridden, which may reduce runtime, but wouldn't actually reduce time complexity.  The worst case would still be the worst case.

Comment: @phatfingers, can you share your idea how to do that, even I tried, but the commands come in sequence, so I am confused how to reduce time.

Comment: For type 1, only the last command is necessary for each unique value of `p`.  All prior `[1, p, ...]` can be eliminated.

Comment: For type 2, you can eliminate all prior type 2's less than or equal to `r`.

Comment: @phatfingers, I removed inner for loop and then I tried find max value for r for type 2's and updated the array accordingly in the end. Its not working, am i missing something here?

Comment: You can't just find the max value for type 2's. Imagine a type 2 for 100 so all elements are now at least 100. Then follows a type 1 setting element 2 to 50. So now all elements are no longer a minimum of 100, because one of them is 50. Then comes another type 2 for 60. That should now set element 2 to 60. But if you only care about the maximum type 2, you will miss the type 2 for 60. As phatfingers said, you need to only discard _prior_ type 2's, not later ones. So if you have a type 2 for 100 and then one for 60, you need to keep both of them.

Comment: @k314159, so for type 2, are you saying I need to keep only decreasing values of r, like 100, 60, etc and ignore increasing ones like 30, 40, 50 etc

Comment: Yes, keep the decreasing values.

Comment: You could also delete some decreasing values if there are no type 1 commands between them and their larger counterpart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to support two commands efficiently:

- `set(i, v)`: Set item at index `i` to value `v`
- `clamp(min)`: Set all items `<= min` to `min`.

Let's look at this per index. For each element, we have a sequence of `set` and `clamp` operations.

Of the `set` operations per index, only the last one matters. Everything that happened before is completely irrelevant, including `clamp` operations. After this `set` operation comes a series of `clamp` operations. Of these, only the largest value of `min` matters.

So here's what we do: We apply the operations *in reverse*, starting with the last operation, and keeping track of a running `max`imum of `min`imums. Once we have `set` an element, clamped to the current `max`, we don't ever need to look at it again. The remaining elements can be filled in using the "default" values from `A`, clamped to the final `max`.

Overall, this should look like this:

```java
public static int[] solve(int[] A, int[][] commands) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    boolean[] initialized = new boolean[A.length]; // note: initialized to false
    int[] items = new int[A.length];
    for (int[] command : Arrays.asList(commands).reversed()) {
        if (command[0] == 1) {
            // set(i, v)
            int i = command[1];
            if (initialized[i])
                continue; // overwritten by a later set operation
            int v = command[2];
            items[i] = Math.max(max, v); // apply clamping of later clamp commands
            initialized[i] = true;
        } else {
            // clamp(min)
            assert command[0] == 2;
            int min = command[2];
            max = Math.max(max, min); // remember most restrictive clamping
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        if (!initialized[i])
            items[i] = Math.max(max, A[i]); // clamped "default" value
    return items;
}
```

which has O(n) time complexity, which is optimal (assuming `A.length <= n`); the constant factors should also be favorably small here.

Testing this on your example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(solve(new int[] {2,4,1,4}, new int[][] {
        {1, 1, 30},
        {1, 2, 4},
        {2, -1, 10},
    })));
}
```

prints `[10, 30, 10, 10]` as expected.

Comment: This looks excellent! By the way, you can get rid of one line and the `j` variable by doing `for (int[] command : Arrays.asList(commands).reversed())`. It will be almost as efficient because `asList` creates a List _view_ of the array, and `reversed()` creattes a reversed _view_ - no copies made.

Comment: @k314159 yep, that's better, edited. Thanks!

Comment: Now you've got an unmatched "}" 

Comment: @k314159 just checking to see if my readers were paying attention ;) totally unrelated to editing my post past midnight.